# flutter sqflite get all data from a table along with it's child table

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite

I have 2 table defines a Task, and it's SubTask:

```
 db.transaction((Transaction txn) async {
      txn.execute("CREATE TABLE ${Tasks.tblTask} ("
          "${Tasks.dbId} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
          "${Tasks.dbServerId} INTEGER,"
          "${Tasks.dbTitle} TEXT,"
          "${Tasks.dbCreateTime} LONG,"
          "${Tasks.dbComment} TEXT,"
          "${Tasks.dbCommentUpdateTime} LONG,"
          "${Tasks.dbDueDate} LONG,"
          "${Tasks.dbDueTime} LONG,"
          "${Tasks.dbCompleteTime} LONG,"
          "${Tasks.dbPriority} LONG,"
          "${Tasks.dbProjectID} LONG,"
          "${Tasks.dbTaskTypeID} LONG,"
          "${Tasks.dbStatus} LONG,"
          "${Tasks.dbTaskColorName} TEXT,"
          "${Tasks.dbTaskColorCode} INTEGER,"
          "${Tasks.dbRepeatedType} INTEGER,"
          "${Tasks.dbRepeatedId} INTEGER,"
          "${Tasks.dbRepeatedPer} INTEGER,"
          "${Tasks.dbRepeatedUnit} INTEGER,"
          "${Tasks.dbRepeatedNumbers} TEXT,"
          "${Tasks.dbUserAddr} TEXT,"
          "${Tasks.dbProgress} REAL,"
          "${Tasks.dbCostTime} INTEGER,"
          "${Tasks.dbShared} INTEGER,"
          "FOREIGN KEY(${Tasks.dbProjectID}) REFERENCES ${Project.tblProject}(${Project.dbId}) ON DELETE CASCADE "
          "UNIQUE (${Tasks.dbCreateTime}));");


db.transaction((Transaction txn) async {
      txn.execute("CREATE TABLE ${SubTask.tblSubTask} ("
          "${SubTask.dbId} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
          "${SubTask.dbTaskId} LONG,"
          "${SubTask.dbTaskServerId} LONG,"
          "${SubTask.dbServerId} LONG,"
          "${SubTask.dbUserAddr} TEXT,"
          "${SubTask.dbTitle} TEXT,"
          "${SubTask.dbComment} TEXT,"
          "${SubTask.dbCommentUpdateTime} LONG,"
          "${SubTask.dbDueTime} LONG,"
          "${SubTask.dbCompleteTime} LONG,"
          "${SubTask.dbCreateTime} LONG,"
          "${SubTask.dbPriority} LONG,"
          "${SubTask.dbTaskTypeID} LONG,"
          "${SubTask.dbStatus} LONG,"
          "${SubTask.dbTaskColorName} TEXT,"
          "${SubTask.dbTaskColorCode} INTEGER,"
          "${SubTask.dbProgress} REAL,"
          "${SubTask.dbCostTime} INTEGER,"
          "FOREIGN KEY(${SubTask.dbTaskId}) REFERENCES ${Tasks.tblTask}(${Tasks.dbId}) ON DELETE CASCADE "
          "UNIQUE (${SubTask.dbCreateTime}));");
    });
```

This is how I defined the 2 Table.

Now, I want get all tasks from table, How should I get All tasks along with it's SubTasks?

**Note**: A task might contains serveral Subtasks.

---

**Update**:

I tried this SQL query, it returns me SubTasks but only first one (rest arent able to retrive):

```
 var result = await txn.rawQuery(
          'SELECT ${Tasks.tblTask}.*,${Project.tblProject}.${Project.dbName},${Project.tblProject}.${Project.dbColorCode},group_concat(${Label.tblLabel}.${Label.dbName}) as labelNames,group_concat(${Label.tblLabel}.${Label.dbColorCode}) as labelColors,'
          '${SubTask}.* '
          'FROM ${Tasks.tblTask} LEFT JOIN ${TaskLabels.tblTaskLabel} ON ${TaskLabels.tblTaskLabel}.${TaskLabels.dbTaskId}=${Tasks.tblTask}.${Tasks.dbId} '
          'LEFT JOIN ${Label.tblLabel} ON ${Label.tblLabel}.${Label.dbId}=${TaskLabels.tblTaskLabel}.${TaskLabels.dbLabelId} '
          'LEFT JOIN ${SubTask.tblSubTask} ON ${SubTask.tblSubTask}.${SubTask.dbTaskId}=${Tasks.tblTask}.${Tasks.dbId} '
          'INNER JOIN ${Project.tblProject} ON ${Tasks.tblTask}.${Tasks.dbProjectID} = ${Project.tblProject}.${Project.dbId} $whereClause GROUP BY ${Tasks.tblTask}.${Tasks.dbId} ORDER BY $sortCondition;');
      return result;
```

What I want, is return my a list of [Task, Task, Task, Task. ....]

and in some Task, it will have a list [SubTask, SubTask ...]
so it looks like:

[Task[SubTask, SubTask], Task, Task[SubTask, SubTask, Subtask]].

As I mentioned on first answer. **I have tried query Tasks out, and the for loop it, then query SubTask of Tasks, but this is slow!!! I deprecated this way already!! I need a single SQL sentence or at least most efficient way to do this**

Comment: I simply need a SQL query to get all tasks and along SubTasks. I found SQL has no way to query an item and it's child list item togather, so please help

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: I just need an SQL sentence to get data, I udpate a breifly result I want

Comment: please share [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self%2Dcontained%20correct%20example.) with sample data.

Comment: I can not provide full example since this is **flutter project**. If you understand my problem, I just need a SQL sentence query all Tasks out and subtasks belongs to each task. I already updated my table configuration.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want subtask which are related to task your SQL query would be something like this:

```
SELECT
  task.id as task_id,
  task.name as task_name,
  sub_task.name as subtask_name,
  sub_task.id as subtask_id
FROM task
LEFT JOIN sub_task
ON task.id = sub_task.task_id
WHERE task.id = 2
```

Suppose you task table is something like:

```
id  name
1   task 1
2   task 2
3   task 3
```

And your sub_task table like:

```
id  name          task_id
1   sub task 1    1
2   sub task 2    2
3   sub task 3    1
4   sub task 4    1
5   sub task 5    3
6   sub task 6    1
7   sub task 7    3
8   sub task 8    2
9   sub task 9    1
10  sub task 10   null
11  sub task 11   null
12  sub task 12   null
```

After query result would be like:

```
task_id task_name   subtask_name    subtask_id
2       task 2      sub task 2      2
2       task 2      sub task 8      8
```

then you can easily use result to create required structure:

```dart
Future<List<Task>> getTasksWithSubtasks() async {
    final Database db = await database; //Get an instance of your Database
    // res would be like this:
    /*
       [
         {
           task_id: 2,
           task_name: "task 2",
           subtask_name: "sub task 2",
           subtask_id: 2
         },
         {
           task_id: 2,
           task_name: "task 2",
           subtask_name: "sub task 8",
           subtask_id: 8
         }
       ]
    */
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> res = await db.rawQuery("""
      SELECT
      task.id as task_id,
      task.name as task_name,
      sub_task.name as subtask_name,
      sub_task.id as subtask_id
      FROM task
      LEFT JOIN sub_task
      ON task.id = sub_task.task_id
      WHERE task.id = 2
    """); // Retrieve all tasks with related subtasks

    List<Task> tasks = [];

    var pos = -1;
    var current = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      if (res[i].task_id == current) {
         tasks[pos].subtasks.add(
           SubTask(
             id: res[i].subtask_id,
             name: res[i].subtask_name
           )
         );
      }
      else {
        current = res[i].task_id;
        pos += 1
        task.add(
           Task(
             id: res[i].task_id,
             name: res[i].task_name,
             subtasks: [SubTask(
               id: res[i].subtask_id,
               name: res[i].subtask_name
             )]
           )
        );
      }
    }
  }
  return tasks;
}
```

Note: you can adjust the SQL query and method for single tasks and related subtasks

**Sample Data SQL**

```sql
drop table if exists task;
Create table task (
  id int,
  name varchar
);
Insert into task (id, name) values(1, "task 1");
Insert into task (id, name) values(2, "task 2");
Insert into task (id, name) values(3, "task 3");
drop table if exists sub_task;
Create table sub_task (
  id int,
  name varchar,
  task_id int
);
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(1, "sub task 1", 1);
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(2, "sub task 2", 2);
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(3, "sub task 3", 1);
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(4, "sub task 4", 1);
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(5, "sub task 5", 3);
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(6, "sub task 6", 1);
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(7, "sub task 7", 3);
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(8, "sub task 8", 2);
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(9, "sub task 9", 1);
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(10, "sub task 10");
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(11, "sub task 11");
Insert into sub_task (id, name, task_id) values(12, "sub task 12");
```

Comment: thank u Sir. This seems a promising answer, But I have tried at least 100 times this **doesn't** work on sqflite. It queries only first SubTask not as a List.  Please allow me attach a screen shot here since charactores no enough: https://z3.ax1x.com/2021/06/04/2JudYD.png  https://z3.ax1x.com/2021/06/04/2JuDld.png  As you see, I query tasks and subtask at same time, only 1 single subtask get, but in detail I query only that Task, it has 3 subtasks

Comment: @NicholasJela can you share database with only the task and related subtask that you have shared in picture.

Comment: thank u Sir, I attached my sample db on github: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/659#issuecomment-855258787 Please make sure help me have a look, since it's not easy for me to upload the source db file.

Comment: @NicholasJela subTask.subTaskTaskId are empty there is only one proper relation for id 0 which i have tested after modifing shared query according to tables in sample data db and it working as expected. here a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/s8kvh9G).

Answer (score 0):

Probably an adaptation of the following code will solve your problem. I say probably because I don't know exactly how yout Task, SubTask models are. And also in the **update** query you run it appears you have more models like Project etc.
I'm sticking with just Task and SubTask as your question is only about those two. The code is moderately commented to highlight its purpose or assumptions.

```dart
  Future<List<Task>> getTasksWithSubtasks() async {
    final Database db = await database; //Get an instance of your Database

    final res = await db
        .query(Tasks.dbId); // Retrieve all tasks with all its attributes

    List<Task> taskList = res.isNotEmpty
        ? res.map((c) => Task.fromJson(c)).toList()
        : []; // Map to objects in your domain

    // Now well retrieve all the subtasks associated with a task by its `id` and add them to the Task
    // I'm assuming that your `Task` model  has an attribute subtasks which is a List<Subtask> 

    for (var task in taskList) {
      var subtasksRaw = await db.query(SubTask.tblSubTask,
          where:
              "${SubTask.dbTaskId}=${task.id}"); // Assuming Task has an attribute `id`

      List<SubTask> subtaskList =
          res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => SubTask.fromJson(c)).toList() : [];

      task.subtasks.addAll(subtaskList);
    }
// Now our model should be as you wanted [Task[SubTask, SubTask], Task[], Task[SubTask, SubTask, Subtask]].
    return taskList;
  }
```

Comment: thank u for your answer Sir. **but this is the way I deprecated, since I querry subTasks inside for loop is very slow**. I want a single SQL sentence query both all Tasks and every SubTask of each task.

Comment: @NicholasJela If you've tried things, and they've not worked, or not worked well enough, you should [edit] the question to include those details.